# How to fix `Failed to set up Chromium` and `server returned code 502` when installing `@mermaid-js\mermaid-cli` ？

Tags: node.js, npm, mermaid

I'm installing @mermaid-js\mermaid-cli as the [installation guildline](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli#installation):

```
npm install -g @mermaid-js/mermaid-cli
```

And the errors shows as:

```
npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r1108766! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
npm ERR! Error: Download failed: server returned code 502. URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/1108766/chrome-win.zip
npm ERR!     at E:\Program Files\miniconda3\envs\pandoc\node_modules\@mermaid-js\mermaid-cli\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\httpUtil.js:121:31
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.requestCallback (E:\Program Files\miniconda3\envs\pandoc\node_modules\@mermaid-js\mermaid-cli\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\httpUtil.js:98:13)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:701:27)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:542:22)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
npm ERR!     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
```

It seems unable to download, install, and set up Chromium. But if I copy the link `https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/1108766/chrome-win.zip` into Edge browser, it actually can download the target.

I've tested on both Windows and WSL2, and tested on both nodejs v18.18 and v20.7, but all of them failed with the same errors.

My question is, how to fix the above errors and install @mermaid-js\mermaid-cli correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried npm upgrade puppeteer before installation? i have run the command npm upgrade puppeteer  first then install mermaid, it run successfully